# Computing cosine_proximity loss between two outputs of the network

Tags: deep-learning, keras, loss

I'm using Keras 2.0.2 Functional API (Tensorflow 1.0.1) to implement a network that takes several inputs and produces two outputs `a` and `b`. I need to train the network using the cosine_proximity loss, such that `b` is the label for `a`. How do I do this?

Sharing my code here. The last line `model.fit(..)` is the problematic part because I don't have labeled data per se. The label is produced by the model itself.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM
from keras import losses

shared_lstm = LSTM(dim)

q1 = Input(shape=(..,.. ), name='q1')
q2 = Input(shape=(..,.. ), name='q2')
a = shared_lstm(q1)
b = shared_lstm(q2)
model = Model(inputs=[q1,q2], outputs=[a, b])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses.cosine_proximity)

model.fit([testq1, testq2], [?????])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a fake true label first. For example, define it as a 1-D array of ones of the size of your input data.

Now comes the loss function. You can write it as follows.

```
def my_cosine_proximity(y_true, y_pred):
    a = y_pred[0]
    b = y_pred[1]
    # depends on whether you want to normalize
    a = K.l2_normalize(a, axis=-1)
    b = K.l2_normalize(b, axis=-1)        
    return -K.mean(a * b, axis=-1) + 0 * y_true
```

I have multiplied `y_true` by zero and added it just so that Theano does give not missing input warning/error.

You should call your `fit` function normally i.e. by including your fake ground-truth labels.

```
model.compile('adam', my_cosine_proximity) # 'adam' used as an example optimizer 
model.fit([testq1, testq2], fake_y_true)
```